# Android tablet - Tabbing through input fields not does not work in forms within iframe

Tags: android, html, forms, iframe

I built an HTML page with a form on it, and I'm embedding that page in an iframe. When navigating to the form page (without viewing through the iframe) on a Motorola Xoom, tabbing though the input fields works as it should. When viewing the page with the iframe on it, tabbing through the form does not work any more. Any thoughts? Insights?

Comment: I have a form that won't tab through at all – it just types a tab into the field :( Rubbish!

Comment: this may be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6815836/navigate-through-the-tab-key

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a browser problem. From the way I understand it, browsers receive the HTML page and skim it for form fields.  This is why you can tab through fields. But the browser probably does not skim iframes for form fields.

As for solving the problem, you could try to eliminate the iframe entirely, and simply embed the form in the page (if you use PHP, you could use the include function).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Unfortunately, I cannot change the use of iframes with forms, or else I totally would.