# How do you make a div "tabbable"?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I have buttons that are div elements and I want to make them so that it is possible for the user to press the tab key on their keyboard and move between them. I've tried wrapping their text in anchor tags but it doesn't seem to work.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: You want to tab between the buttons? Or the divs?

Comment: If the anchor has an `href` attribute it should work. It may or may not be an appropriate use of the markup unless the activatable item actually does something.

Comment: Question has been asked
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059203/tab-index-on-div

Comment: Thank you, the href solution works best! Tim, if you provide an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 180, accepted):

Add `tabindex` attributes to your `div` elements.

Example:

```
<div tabindex="1">First</div>
<div tabindex="2">Second</div>
```

Per steveax's comment, if you don't want the tab order to deviate from where the element is in the page, set the `tabindex` to `0`:

```
<div tabindex="0">First</div>
<div tabindex="0">Second</div>
```

Comment: NB: tabindex is not a valid attribute of divs in HTML <5. [Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-tabindex) {Corrected after Neps pointed out my error}

Comment: @Dancrumb, yes they are in HTML5

Comment: Probably better to use `tabindex=0` though so as to not muck with the natural tabbing order.

Comment: btw, this doesn't allow one to click it with enter though.

Comment: Hmn, @Ciantic any idea how we can work around or simulate a click on enter while tabbed to that div? hmn

Comment: You can simulate a click by adding an **onkeypress** event function. In this function, you must 1) prevent the default action, 2) inspect the key pressed and if it is a key that should send a click, trigger a click on the element in code.

Answer (score 8):

for those interested, in addition to the accepted answer, you can add the following jquery to make the div style change when you tab to it, and also handle Enter and Space to trigger a click (then your click handler will do the rest)

```
$(document).on('focus', '.button',function(){
    $(this).css('border','1px dotted black')
});
$(document).on('keyup', '.button',function(e){
    if(e.which==13 || e.which==32)
        $(this).click()
});
```

I'm sure someone has made this into a jq plugin $().makeTabStop

Comment: I believe it is better to use the keydown event instead of the keyup event as recommended here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/Keyboard-navigable_JavaScript_widgets. An apparent advantage of keydown is that if you return false from your hander function (after the click() call), it will correctly stop the propagation of the event elsewhere on the page, whereas with keyup this doesn't work.

Comment: Space might also scroll the page. You might need to use the preventDefault function as well.

Answer (score 6):

Add the `tabindex="0"`attribute to each div you want tabbable. Then use CSS pseudo classes :hover and :focus, for example to signify to the app user that the div is in focus and clickable, for example. Use JavaScript to handle the click.

```js
var doc = document;
var providers = doc.getElementsByClassName("provider");

for (var i = 0; i < providers.length; i++) {
    providers[i].onclick = function() {
      console.log(this.innerHTML);
    };
}
```

```css
.provider {
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    align-self: auto;
    width: 256px;
    height: 48px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    margin-right: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 48px;
    
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 10%;
    background-color: gray;
}

.provider:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
}

.provider:focus{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 8px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 8px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 8px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
```

```html
<h4>Click in this area first then press tab</h4>
<div id="email" class="provider" tabindex="0">email</div>
<div id="facebook" class="provider" tabindex="0">facebook</div>
<div id="github" class="provider" tabindex="0">github</div>
<div id="google" class="provider" tabindex="0">google</div>
<div id="twitter" class="provider" tabindex="0">twitter</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

## Make elements tabbable and clickable with key press using jquery

Assumptions

- All elements that are of a non-tabbable, non-clickable type and should be clickable have an **onclick** attribute (this could be changed to a class or other attribute)
- All elements are of the same type; I will use divs.
- You're using jquery

Sample html:

```
...

<div onclick="clicked(this)">Button 1</div>
<div onclick="clicked(this)">Button 2</div>
<div onclick="clicked(this)">Button 3</div>

...
```

Jquery code:
This is the code that will run when the page has loaded. It needs to run on your HTML page.

```js
$(()=>{
    // make divs with an onclick attribute tabbable/clickable
    $('div[onclick]')
        .attr('tabindex', '0')                     // Add tab indexes
        .keypress((evt)=>{
            var key = evt.key;
            evt.preventDefault();                  // Ensure all default keypress
                                                   // actions are not used
            if (key === ' ' || key === 'Enter') {  // Only send click events for Space
                                                   // or Enter keys
                evt.currentTarget.click();         // Run the click event for element
            }
        });
});
```

You can find a working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1nawy0kj/).

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that shows up on this page for the opposite intention, as in to make a div tag NOT tabbable: https://github.com/WICG/inert is a good way.