# full website control with keyboard (no mouse)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, accessibility

So I started creating a site (html, css, js..) and I want to design my site so it's possible for someone without a mouse (just a keyboard) can use it.

If I have a `div` or `li` element, how can I make it get focus with <strike>tab or</strike> down arrow on the keyboard?

Example:

```
<ul class="nav-ul">
<li>
    <a href="" class="nav-link" id="link-home">1
        <img src="assets/home.png">
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="" class="nav-link" id="link-home">2
        <img src="assets/home.png">
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="" class="nav-link" id="link-home">3
        <img src="assets/home.png">
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="" class="nav-link" id="link-home">4
        <img src="assets/home.png">
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="" class="nav-link" id="link-home">5
        <img src="assets/home.png">
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="" class="nav-link" id="link-home">6
        <img src="assets/home.png">
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="" class="nav-link" id="link-home">7
        <img src="assets/home.png">
    </a>
</li>
```

Here, I want each `li` element to gain focus when down arrow is pressed on the keyboard.

**EDIT:**
`tabindex` DOES NOT WORK! i tried it many different ways. I want to have the same effect as it does when I hover over it.

**EDIT 2**

So I will make my question for clear. I do NOT want to use tab but instead it will be a D-pad (left, right, top, and bottom arrows).

Thank you.

Comment: tabindex http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13637223/how-do-you-make-a-div-tabbable

Comment: Tried it as I was posting this. Doesn't work. I want it to have the same effect it has when I hover it with a mouse. I don't see any changes with `tabindex`

Comment: There is some reference here for keypress event particular down arrow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19347269/jquery-keypress-arrow-keys

Comment: I would generally advise against implementing non-standard behaviour of arrow keys. Most people who are going to use them will be expecting them to scroll the document.

Comment: I wish I could +100 Quentins comment. If your going to do the important step of making your site accessible, stick to the standards.

Comment: @SmitPatel, if you want to verify that keyboard-only users are going to be able to use your site, I'd recommend testing with an actual screen reader (such as http://www.nvaccess.org/). Much of what you're describing is default behavior for screen reading software.

Comment: I understand that but this is a very unique scenario where there is a special remote with a D-pad and that's the only thing the user can use to navigate through website.  Scrolling wont be an issue because it will not overflow and fit on the screen

Comment: I have added the answer which focus the hyperlink instead of li so user can click the respective link.

Comment: Also, look at the Adobe Mega Menu: https://adobe-accessibility.github.io/Accessible-Mega-Menu/ In particular, pay attention to the use of roles. Once you start to support arrow keys, many screen reader / assistive tech users have an expectation that it will behaving like an OS menu, which means a lot more scripting and roles management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achive this is to use `tabindex` attribute.

```
<li>
    <a href="" class="nav-link" id="link-home" tabindex='7'>7
        <img src="assets/home.png">
    </a>
</li>
```

Check some examples [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_tabindex.asp)

**EDIT**
Navigating with left and right arrow:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
   var focused = document.activeElement || document.body,
       focusables= document.getElementsByClassName("focusable"),
       len = focusables.length,
       step = 0;
   focusables = Array.from(focusables).sort(function(a,b) {
       return parseInt(a.tabIndex) - parseInt(b.tabIndex);
   });
   if (e.keyCode === 39) {
       step = 1
   }
   if (e.keyCode === 37) {
       step = -1
   }

   if (focused.tabIndex <0 || focused.tabIndex === len - 1 && step === 1) 
       focusables[0].focus()
   else if (focused.tabIndex === 0 && step === -1) 
       focusables[len-1].focus()
   else
       focusables[focused.tabIndex+step].focus()
});
```

Anything you need to do is to make your elements like this:

```
<a href="" class="nav-link focusable" id="link-home" tabindex="0">1
    <img src="assets/home.png">
</a>
```

Adding class `focusable` and setting `tabindex`
Working [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mPoZmd)

Comment: Take a look here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mPoZmd click on white space below your list and press tabs. Watch which list element gets focused

Comment: Ok I understand. I edited my question. Sorry i wasnt clear. Please see EDIT 2 in my question

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```js
var target = 1;
downarrow();
uparrow();
function downarrow() {
  $(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 40) {
      $('#' + target).addClass('active');
      $('#' + target).focus();
      $('a').not($('#' + target)).removeClass('active');
      target++;
    } 
    if (target === 8) {
     target = 1;
    };
  });
};
function uparrow() {
  $(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 38) {
      target--;
      if (target === 0) {
       target = 7;
      };
      $('#' + target).addClass('active');
      $('#' + target).focus();
      $('a').not($('#' + target)).removeClass('active');
    } 
  });
};
```

```css
a.active {
  background-color: #b2b2b2;
  outline: 1px solid red ;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav-ul">
<li>
    <a id="1" href="" class="nav-link" id="link-home">1
        <img src="assets/home.png">
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a id="2" href="" class="nav-link" id="link-home">2
        <img src="assets/home.png">
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a id="3" href="" class="nav-link" id="link-home">3
        <img src="assets/home.png">
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a id="4" href="" class="nav-link" id="link-home">4
        <img src="assets/home.png">
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a id="5" href="" class="nav-link" id="link-home">5
        <img src="assets/home.png">
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a id="6" href="" class="nav-link" id="link-home">6
        <img src="assets/home.png">
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a id="7" href="" class="nav-link" id="link-home">7
        <img src="assets/home.png">
    </a>
</li>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jpjr1nbt/5/

REMARKS:

If you also want up arrow to scroll up. the keyCode is 38

Comment: this is great! I just prefer to do it simply (without ajax) so I decided to go with  xosjasx's answer. thanks!