# Enter key press on <li> with Vue3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

Have this code:

```
<li v-for="(dog, index) in dogs" :key="index" class=" hover:bg-gray-50" :class="{ 'bg-red-50': index === focus }" @keyup.enter="goToSlug(dog)"> .... </li>
```

I handle the focus perfectly, but want to run the method goToSlug() on key enter be pressed. It doesn't fire the method.

Comment: You need the li element to have focus, for key events to fire. You can use vuejs refs to set focus to that element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Key presses are only registered on items that have focus.

In order to make an element like a `<li>` tag focusable (which natively does not have that ability) you will need to add another attribute called `tabindex='1'` (1 being an arbitrary value here, but you can read more up on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13637223/how-do-you-make-a-div-tabbable)).

So in your case:

```
<li 
  v-for="(dog, index) in dogs" 
  tabindex="1" 
  :key="index" 
  class=" hover:bg-gray-50" 
  :class="{ 'bg-red-50': index === focus }" 
  @keyup.enter="goToSlug(dog)"
> .... 
</li>
```

Now, in order to register a key press on this (or its siblings) just tab through them and press enter when you have the desired target.

Comment: It's better to add: tabindex="0", that way you let the browser decide the order in which the focuable-elements will be visited. If you choose for a non-negative number, you have to keep track of the tab-order, which is defined by tabindex