# What HTML elements are not tabbable even with tabindex?

Tags: html, focus, keyboard-navigation

Does anyone have a list of the HTML (HTML5) elements that are **not** tabbable, even if a tabindex is specified? (By tabbable, I mean that they can receive the focus through repeatedly pressing the "tab" key.)

We know that there are those elements which are tabbable by default, such as `input` or `textarea`. We also know that there are some elements which are only tabbable if a tabindex is explicitly specified, such as `div` and `span` elements.

According to W3Schools, "In HTML5, the tabindex attribute can be used on any HTML element". However, there are surely some elements which are not tabbable even if they have a tabindex. For example, it makes no sense for the `param` element to be tabbable, or the `head` element. I also don't really think it's possible for the `option` element to be tabbable, but I'm not sure about that. And I'm even less sure about things like `map` which can contain tabbable elements but are not usually tabbable themselves.

Can someone give me a list of all the elements that can never receive focus even if they have a tabindex?

Comment: Did you test whether the head element is actually not tabbable?

Comment: No I haven't tested it. I just gave that as an example.

Comment: I just tested in Chrome 17.x and found that the `head` element is not tabbable. Neither is `title` or `param`, but the `option` element is tabbable (only if you provide a tabindex, obviously). That still does not answer my question though.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059203/tab-index-on-div

Comment: @BillyMoat that's not helpful I'm afraid, it just states about not being able to use tabindex with div in html4, my question is really asking about html5. (Following your comment, I edited the question body to mention that specifically, although I feel uncomfortable about doing that because I am of the WHATWG-style opinion that there is no such thing as html5!)

Comment: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/wiki/ChangedAttributeTabindex

Comment: That link doesn't provide any information not in the text of my question. What part of that link answers my question?

Comment: @Kidburla - head and title *are* tabable if they are displayed. See http://jsfiddle.net/tbEPR/. Elements can only be tabbed to if they are displayed, so those that cannot ever be displayed won't be tabable.

Comment: I have found that `object` is not tabbable, even if it displayed. Also, where can I find a list of those elements that can be displayed?

Comment: PS, strangely, that "title" thing seems to work within jsFiddle, but not in a standalone page :S Maybe because jsFiddle is rendering the result in an iframe, which changes the displayability of the title.

Comment: "there are surely some elements which are not tabbable" really?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since no one has yet come up with any kind of definitive list, I did some testing on a fairly recent version of Chrome and came up with the following list of elements which are not tabbable at all:

- `<base>`
- `<basefont>`
- `<embed>`
- `<head>`
- `<link>`
- `<meta>`
- `<object>`
- `<param>`
- `<source>`
- `<style>`
- `<title>`
- `<track>`

Unfortunately, since I only spent a couple of hours trying to write this list, it has a few caveats:

1. Not tested on any browser other than Chrome
2. I skipped over most of the elements that I thought likely to be tabbable (as they would have normal displayed content)
3. I have not tried setting any of these to be displayed (apart from `<title>` as in my comments)

I was most surprised that the following elements **are** tabbable:

- `<audio>` and `<video>` (surprised because `<embed>` and `<object>` are not)
- `<br>` and `<wbr>`
- `<col>` and `<colgroup>`
- `<frame>` and `<frameset>` (although they are more of a special case as they are not technically valid elements in HTML anyway)
- `<html>` (there is almost no difference between this and `<body>` from a tabbing perspective)
- `<optgroup>` and `<option>` (although tabbing to them does not give any visual indication - i.e. the select box does not open)

Comment: Adding @Kidburla's comment to the answer, rather than the question, to make it easier for others to read, as it's referred to in the answer itself: `"PS, strangely, that "title" thing seems to work within jsFiddle, but not in a standalone page :S Maybe because jsFiddle is rendering the result in an iframe, which changes the displayability of the title. – Kidburla Jan 4 '13 at 17:59"`

Answer (score 8):

[The HTML spec lists conditions under which elements are focusable](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/editing.html#focusable) and [how tabindex is interpreted](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/editing.html#sequential-focus-navigation-and-the-tabindex-attribute).

- The element's tabindex focus flag is set.
- The element is either being rendered or  is a descendant of a canvas element that represents embedded content.
- Neither the element nor any of its ancestors are inert.
- The element is not disabled.

The definition relies on elements being rendered, and with CSS you can make *any* element rendered. For example, a focusable `<param>` and even `<title>` and `<basefont>`:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<title tabindex=0>Test</title>
<basefont tabindex=0>
<style>
head, title {display:block}
basefont, param {content: url(image.png);}
</style>
<object><param tabindex=0></object>
```

BTW: Ignore W3Schools — generally that's not a reliable/authoritative source.

Comment: Hi there. First of all, in general I agree with you about W3Schools and hesitated to refer to them. But this was the simplest quote I could find that summarised what I know to be true about the applicability of the tabindex attribute. Thanks for the links you provide. However I can't see anything in there that specifically exclude any element such as `<param>` from being tabbable. In particular, the WHATWG seem to have a fairly odd definition of the term "being rendered" that relies on style properties and so includes elements with no visual content whatsoever.

Comment: @Kidburla indeed, there's nothing in the spec that forbids it. It doesn't need to — it may just treat all elements the same, and it works. Content can be added with CSS. I've updated my example with a focusable `<param>`.

Comment: It doesn't really work as expected. I'm not sure how to test with the exact example you've given. But try adding a little `<a tabindex=1>aa</a><a tabindex=3>bb</a>` at the end and then changing the param's tabindex to 2. You will see that the tab order moves straight from the element "aa" to "bb" and skips out the `<param>` altogether.

Comment: @Kidburla that's just how `tabindex` works, regardless of type of elements involved. Non-0 `tabindex` is a can of worms you don't want to open.

Comment: That's not true. `tabindex` works as you would expect. If your element had been some element which I would consider as "tabbable" (such as `input`, `a` etc) then the tab order would follow through that element. You can try it yourself.