# Changing focus to an element on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, accessibility

## Problem:

I have a back to top arrow `.fa-caret-up` at the bottom of the page, looking to change the focus after the arrow is clicked to either the window or the logo `.logo` at the top left corner of the page.

## Where I'm At

I see it `console.log("Does this work?")` but when I tab it's not in the normal tab order and it takes me to "Leaving HTML content" in the Mac screen reader.

### scripts.js

```
$(function() {
  // This plays videos on click, so beautiful
  $("video").click(function (e) {
  if(e.offsetY < ($(this).height() - 36)) // Check to see if controls where clicked
  {
    if(this.paused)
      this.play();
    else
      this.pause();
  }
});

// Smooth scroll like butter
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
  if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
    var target = $(this.hash);
    target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
    if (target.length) {
      $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top
      }, 1000);
      return false;
    }
  }
});

// FOR IMAGES
// Needs fixing but on the right track
// var fadeImg = $("img").fadeTo(0, 0);

// $(window).scroll(function() {
//     fadeImg.each(function(i) {
//         a = $(this).offset().top + $(this).height();
//         b = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
//         if (a < b) $(this).fadeTo(500,1);
//     });
// });

  // Accessibility consideration, change focus from nav to header in story on click
  $('.chp1').click(function (evt){
    $("#1").focus();
    evt.preventDefault();
  });

  $('.chp2').click(function (evt){
    $("#2").focus();
    evt.preventDefault();
  });

  $('.chp3').click(function (evt){
    $("#3").focus();
    evt.preventDefault();
  });

  $('.chp4').click(function (evt){
    $("#4").focus();
    evt.preventDefault();
  });

  $('.chp5').click(function (evt){
    $("#5").focus();
    evt.preventDefault();
  });

  $('.fa-caret-up').click(function (){
    $('.logo').focus();
    console.log("Does this work?");
  });

  // If mouse hovers over "Reading section", change two elements to yellow
  $('.reading').mouseover(function(){
    $('.fa-clock-o').addClass('yellow');
    $('.min').addClass('yellow');
  });

  // If mouseout, then change back to default colour
  $('.reading').mouseout(function(){
    $('.fa-clock-o').removeClass('yellow');
    $('.min').removeClass('yellow');
  });

  // If mouse hovers over "Listen section", change two elements to yellow
  $('.listen').mouseover(function(){
    $('.fa-headphones').addClass('yellow');
    $('.lis').addClass('yellow');
  });

  // If mouseout, then change back to default colour
  $('.listen').mouseout(function(){
    $('.fa-headphones').removeClass('yellow');
    $('.lis').removeClass('yellow');
  });
});
```

### index.html

```
<nav>
        <div class="navGroup">
            <a href="http://brandonsun.com" target="_blank"><img src="assets/img/branding/sq.png" alt="Brandon Sun logo. Click this image to go to the main site." class="logo"></a>

            <p class="featureTitle" tabindex="0" role="heading">Asbestos</p>

            <ul>
                <a href="#1" tabindex="0" class="chp1"><span class="acc">Chapter 1: Name of Chapter.</span><li>1</li></a>
                <a href="#2" tabindex="0" class="chp2"><span class="acc">Chapter 2: Name of Chapter.</span><li>2</li></a>
                <a href="#3" tabindex="0" class="chp3"><span class="acc">Chapter 3: Name of Chapter.</span><li>3</li></a>
                <a href="#4" tabindex="0" class="chp4"><span class="acc">Chapter 4: Name of Chapter.</span><li>4</li></a>
                <a href="#5" tabindex="0" class="chp5"><span class="acc">Chapter 5: Name of Chapter.</span><li>5</li></a>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navGroup -->
</nav>
                <footer>
                    <div class="thanks">
                        <p class="credits" tabindex="0">
                            Photographer: <span class="bold" alt="Bruce Bumstead">Bruce Bumstead</span><br>
                            Reporter: <span class="bold" alt="Matt Goerzen">Matt Goerzen</span><br>
                            Developer: <span class="bold" alt="and Andrew Nguyen">Andrew Nguyen</span>
                        </p>
                    </div><!-- /.thanks -->
                    <a href="#" id="#" tabindex="0"><span class="acc">Go back to the top of the article</span><i class="fa fa-caret-up fa-2x" ></i></a>
                </footer>
```

Comment: Where's .logo in the html? didn't see it in the example.

Comment: Why tabindex=0 for all ?

Comment: This is a reduced example of my `index.html` that has the `<nav>` with the `.logo` and footer with the `.fa-caret-up` I've included `tabindex=0` on some elements to ensure they are in the normal tab order. However, when I click on the back to top arrow in my footer, it doesn't start the tab order from `.logo` it chooses to "Leave HTML content" instead.

Comment: My guess is that .focus() doesn't like that you're calling it on a potential collection, try using an ID query instead of a class query.  For example what would .focus() do if you had multiple "logo" classes?  Just adding as a comment because I can't verify answer at the moment.

Comment: @lukevp I only have a single logo class, tried with an ID and it did not work either.

Comment: so if you hit tab 3 times from logo being the first selection assuming you expect to be where?

Answer (score 2):

Brandon-boone is correct in the diagnosis of the problem, however, I would change the solution to focus on the anchor that is around the image as this is already naturally focusable and, given that it can be interacted-with, what you will want to focus on anyway.

Change the code to:

```
  $('.fa-caret-up').click(function (){
    $('.logo').parent().focus();
    console.log("Does this work?");
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only focus elements with a tabindex. In your case, trying to focus the node `<img class='logo' />` fails because it does not have a default tab index. Adding a `tabindex='0'` to the element will allow you to `.focus()` the element successfully.

`<img src="assets/img/branding/sq.png" alt="Brandon Sun logo. Click this image to go to the main site." class="logo" tabindex="0">`

More info: [What HTML elements are not tabbable even with tabindex?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14159928/402706)