# css pseudo-class selector why not working on :focus div

Tags: html, css

When the mouse hover on the menus,the menu items can show up,but I want to use "Tab" key to focus on the menu and the menu items can show up,but it doesn't work,how can I fix it?

Here's HTML

```
<ul class="hMenu">
        <li><a href="">prod1</a>
            <div>
                <a href="">test1</a>
                <a href="">test2</a>
                <a href="">test3</a>                    
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" >prod2</a>
            <div>                                               
                <a href="">test4</a>    
                <a href="">test5</a>                    
            </div>
        </li>    
    </ul>
```

Here's css:

```
ul.hMenu li:hover a { color:red;}           
        ul.hMenu li div table{  background-color:yellow;}    
        ul.hMenu  { 
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0; 
            z-index: 1;                 
        }
        ul.hMenu li  {  
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            list-style: none;
            float: left;
            width:140px;
        }
        ul.hMenu li a { 
            display: block; 
            text-align: left;
            text-decoration: none
        }          
        ul.hMenu li div  {                    
            position: absolute;             
            display: none;                
        }
        ul.hMenu div a {background: yellow;     
        }
        ul.hMenu li :hover   {  background: yellow}
        /**Mouse hover the menus can show up**/
        ul.hMenu li:hover   div{            
            display:block;
        }
        /**Why this line can not work when the "Tab" to focus on the menu？**/
        ul.hMenu li :focus  div{            
            display:block;
        }
```

Comment: see if this may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059203/tab-index-on-div

Comment: do you want something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Ab2wd/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
ul.hMenu li a:focus + div{            
        display:block;
    }
```

Example: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rZneg/)

And play around a bit with

```
 tabindex="myNumber"
```

in the appropriate html elements :)

Comment: Yes,It's working now，thanks very much.
Now I want to change the menus as:"When the menu is focused and press the enter key then the menu items will show up,and press Tab to select the menu items,press ESC to hidden the menu items",how to change the css code? I find :visited,:active don't work when I press the enter key.

Comment: First of all: if an answer is working for you, mark it as solution (accepted answer). That way, other people having simular questions don't have to search that much :) About your new wishes: have a look at [this article](http://terrillthompson.com/blog/202)

Comment: this is a typical solution but it doesn't actually address the problem. Why isn't :focus working without the use of a link or input ??

Answer (score 3):

If you have copied the code directly, what I see is that you have a space between your li and focus. 
Please remove the spaces between :hover or :focus and the previous element and try again.

Adding a space means you are referring to a descendant element which is not the case.

Comment: Not just _child_ elements, but all _descendant_ elements.

Comment: True, cant argue with that :) - fixed

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
ul.hMenu li:focus  div{            
    display:block;
}
```

And

```
ul.hMenu li:hover   {  background: yellow}
```