# Can't get data-id after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the `data-id` attribute after a click on the appropriate div. This is my html structure:

```
<div id="existing-risorse-list">
   <div data-id="30">Cabina Cb</div>
   <div data-id="32">Risorsa1 R1</div>
   <div data-id="33">Cabina2 Cb2</div>
</div>
```

Essentially when the user click on `Cabina Cb` I want return the id `30`, this is my code:

```
$(document).on('click', '#existing-risorse-list div', function() 
{
    var this_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    alert(this_id); 
});
```

the event is fired correctly but the alert return

> undefined

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4bpcrvqo/1/ ?

Comment: Impossible......it should work properly

Comment: Syntax error.. Close the brackets.

Comment: @Jss : how are you adding data attribute to elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u3j4oj8o/)

```
$("#existing-risorse-list div").on('click', function() 
{
    var this_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    alert(this_id); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@Diptox code works but **isn't very performant**, the original code in your question is a better way of doing it, as the event is on a single element. the issue *maybe* caused by you targeting `$(document)` a simple solution is to target `#existing-risorse-list` eg:

```
$("#existing-risorse-list").on('click','div', function() 
{
    var this_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    alert(this_id); 
});
```

Hope that helps

Comment: On a side note, it would be much better if the interactive elements, eg `<div data-id="30">` could be focused via tabbing, this can be [achieved by adding a tabIndex] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059203/tab-index-on-div) `<div data-id="30"  tabindex="0">` or even better converting the `div`s to links `<a href="?id=30" data-id="30">Cabina Cb</a>` you could maybe then have a no js version?!?