# WCAG accessibility issue with nested elements

Tags: html, css, focus, accessibility, wcag

I've grid with several boxes in (`<div>`). Each box has inside a list with couple/ several links (simple `ul li` list with `<a>` elements). This link list is hidden, it shows only on hover.

It works really fine, but I have accessibility issue, namely, I can't get into any list element with "tab" key (box `<div>` works ok, it get focus, so the list is showing up), it is just skipping to next box element. I've tried with adding `tabindex` on each box and each list element inside, but it seems that this is not the solution.

Is there any CSS/ HTML solution for that? I can of course write simple JS, that will check where is focus and if focus has parent with focus option, but I would like to avoid it if possible.

Comment: try to use tabinex http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059203/tab-index-on-div

Comment: As I said, I've used tabindex on both box element and all child element inside, but unfortunately, I'm not able to get into any descent elements

Comment: could you put your code, and we'll see better, tks

Comment: yes, posting code would help.  i'm using a <li> with tabindex and it works great with a keyboard.

Comment: I'm also a little puzzled by your comment about having a link that is hidden unless you hover.  does that mean you need to use a mouse to see it?  keyboard won't work?

Comment: You probably have the same problem with touch (on tablets, smartphones and… laptops and monitors with touch included) that you've with keyboad/focus and though it may be corrected with JS, I'd advise adding toggle buttons so user can toggle visibility whatever its interaction mode with your page

Answer (score 1):

- How did you hide the link list? Using `display: none` or using `visibility: hidden`. (And that you apply this only to the list elements or also to the div? From your description, I guess it applies only to the list elements.) Content that is hidden using `display: none` is not keyboard accessible.
- In order to make the list appear on hover, are you using a JavaScript event handler or CSS? If you are using JavaScript, you probably need to add an event listener that responds to keyboard events (e.g. `onfocus`, but as mentioned above, content hidden with `display: none` won't receive focus). In CSS, I always recommend adding the `:focus` pseudo-class whenever `:hover` is used (unless you want different styles for these things).
- You may need to write some JavaScript that toggles the visibility of the lists when a parent `div` receives focus. (If you have `tabindex` on the `div` elements, as you say, they should already be able to receive focus.)