# Focus and trigger enter key on div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page which has got many div under anchor tag.

```
<a>
    <div onclick=alert("Hi First div");>First</div>
</a>
<a>
    <div onclick=alert("Hi Second div");>Second</div>
</a>.......
```

I have onclick event on every div which is working fine as i click on the div.

Is there a way i can traverse every div using tab (with/without using tabindex)and on click of enter key on keyboard the alert is appeared without writing any JS?

I am only trying to acheive this for accessibility.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059203/tab-index-on-div

Comment: Is there any special reason to not tab the anchor tags instead? Would give you wider browser support and everything works by itself kinda.

Comment: Look at this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059203/tab-index-on-div

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is to set tabindex behaviour on elements that do not support it.

There is an explanation in this other question.

Look at this question. [Tab Index on div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059203/tab-index-on-div)

Comment: I miss the part where images are getting mentioned. Care to elaborate?

Comment: Ah ok - just reread the question and I see that there is no mention of images. I will edit out that part of the answer. Actually I think your answer @Lain is best as the OP can style the anchors like divs anyway. Well done I will upvote yours.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I can not see any reason to not make use of the anchor tags built in behavior:

```
<a href = '#' onclick = 'alert("Hi First div");' tabindex = '1'>First</a>
<a href = '#' onclick = 'alert("Hi Second div");' tabindex = '2'>Second</a>
```