# .focus() does not work on 'p' tag through jquery

Tags: jquery

When I try to focus the `p` tag using the below line, it is not getting highlighted. Can somebody help me to get highlighted.

```js
$("#tabFocus").focus();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Search icon on a styled button:
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search
  </button>
</p>
<p id="tabFocus">
  Print icon: <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></i>
</p>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tab Index on div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059203/tab-index-on-div)

Comment: @Rory McCrossan: So how to achieve default behavior  when I focus on 'p' tag. Can i highlight it through my jQuery code as browser highlight.

Comment: Yes, see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a `p` element (or any other element besides `a` or a form control) to receive focus you need to place a `tabindex` attribute on it. Then you can style it with the `:focus` selector to achieve your 'highlight' effect:

```js
$("#tabFocus").focus();
```

```css
p:focus {
  color: #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Search icon on a styled button:
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search
  </button>
</p>
<p id="tabFocus" tabindex="0">
  Print icon: <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></i>
</p>
```

Note that adding superfluous `tabindex` attributes may negatively affect the UX for users who navigate your site using the keyboard, though.